# Android webview can't connect to local ip address

Tags: android, mobile, webview

I've got a webView class in a simple android app.  I'm trying to get webView to load a webpage hosted on a server on my local network and it can't connect.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
webview.loadUrl("192.168.1.104");
```

webView says 'web page not available'

I can connect to 192.168.1.104 in a regular browser and any mobile browser.
When I replace `192.168.1.104` with `http://example.com` it works.

Comment: I'm assuming your phone is connected to same network already and though all I can think of would be adding protocol to your URL ``http://192.168.1.104``. Maybe it helped.

Comment: yes the phone is on the same network as the 192.168.1.104.  When I add http:// to the local url, the webview launches a browser on my phone with that address.

Comment: Where is the port number of the web app that you're running? What is the logcat output? Is internet permission given in your manifest? Does any other website launches from your emulator browser?

Answer (score 4):

Did you add the internet permission to the AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

just add those code below it will show your page in lan:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entering onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/SampleWebServer/Welcome.html");
        Log.i(TAG,"Exiting onCreate");
}
```

**mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);**

that's it!

Comment: that's indeed it!